# How to refund transaction in paypal? PHP Code

Tags: paypal

How to refund a transaction at once after pay? I use express checkout and need to refund payments atonce after pay if user paid for some product by mistake.
I found some link:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/refund-payment/
But it seems to be wrong, because seems I have to send not only transaction id.

If just send curl post with a transaction id, what is non-sandbox link for refund? 
I'm doing it via API

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that paypal is not sending you a transaction id?
Try to do a var dump on $_GET['id'] and see if you get anything... or just check if you get any response in the url. else something is going wrong.